# Python Scrape of Wikipedia table then export to csv

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, export-to-csv

I have followed a tuitorial to scrape a table then export the data to a csv file. I am getting an error through PyCharm when I try to execute the file saying

" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:/Scrape/MediumCode.py", line 1, in 
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' "

I also assume that there are other errors in code and its logic but this is the first problem Ive ran into and cant go further without understanding why the library isnt recognized

ran pip install requests with success

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Switzerland'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("table", {"class":"wikitable"})

filename = "holidays.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "holiday, holiday_date"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    holiday = container.table.tbody.tr.td.a["title"]

    name_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"title"})
    holiday_name = name_container[0].text

    date_container = container.findAll("td")
    date = date_container[0].text.strip()

    print("holiday: " + brand)
    print("holiday_name: " + holiday_name)
    print("date: " + date)

    f.write(holiday + "," + holiday_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + date + "\n")

    f.close()
```

Comment: same error when adding import requests as first line

Comment: Try running the line `import requests` in a totally separate file containing nothing else and see if you get the same error.

Comment: no output of the same error

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas` library

- [`.read_html(`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html)) - Read HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects.
- [`.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) - Write object to a comma-separated values (csv) file.

---

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Switzerland'
response = requests.get(url)

tables = pd.read_html(response.text)

# write holiday table data into `holiday_data` csv file
tables[0].to_csv("holiday_data.csv")
```

> Install pandas library

```
pip3 install pandas
```

If `requests` library still not throw an error in your system try this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Switzerland'
response = uReq(url)
tables = pd.read_html(response.read())
#select only holiday column
select_table_column = ["Holiday"]
'''
    #or select multiple columns 
    select_table_column = ["Holiday","Date"]

'''
# filter table data by selected columns
holiday = tables[0][select_table_column]

# # write holiday table data into `holiday_data` csv file and set csv header
holiday.to_csv("holiday_data.csv",header=True)
```

Comment: requests still throwing error in 1st code you posted. not getting any errors now with the second piece of code you posted! Thanks!!

Comment: now if i only wanted to grab the first select columns how would i iterate through them?

Comment: could you merge those two sections of code together? I am replacing the tables[0].to_csv("holiday_data.csv") with the updated code and am having issues

Comment: @ERich ANswer Updated, check it.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, I'm able to obtain `page_html` just fine. So your system doesn't like `urllib.request` for some reason. Note that `request` isn't quite the same as `requests`. As I understand it, `requests` is built on top of `urllib3`, whereas `urllib.request` is in the standard library, even though they both point to some common things under the hood.

Does this code work for you?

```
from urllib import request

my_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Switzerland'
p = request.urlopen(my_url)
print(p.read())
```

Comment: switched from PyCharm to Anaconda/Spyder and yes it does work. Running my code above in the Spyder IDE now throws these errors                               
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-1c82fa9c02c9>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Riche10/.spyder-py3/Test_Scraper.py', wdir='C:/Users/Riche10/.spyder-py3')